# rails 2.3.7 issues with content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-formatting, content-for

I have an application where I want to render the menu using "content_for" as well as a left navigation bar and then the rest be the body of my document. However, in my left bar and menu regions, the html markup is being escaped. I saw a post regarding using raw before the yield, but that didn't help.

After spending quite some time trying to diagnose it within the real app, I created a VERY simple test and was able to get it to do the same with minimal code. Here is what I have:

layouts.application.erb

```
  <body>
     <section id="page">
        <header>
          <nav class="clear"><%= raw yield :navigation %></nav>
        </header>

       <%= yield %>

     </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

pages/index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :navigation do %>
  <ul><li><%= link_to 'New page', new_page_path %></li></ul>
<% end %>

<h1>Listing pages</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
  </tr>

<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h page.title %></td>
    <td><%=h page.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', page %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_page_path(page) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', page, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

When I hit the page in a browser, the navigation part is not escaped properly (actually the link is, but not the list, which is kinda important with menus:) )

This is from a brand new rails project using scaffold generated code which was modified only to move the default link up into the navigation section (and adding that piece in).

Answer (score 0):

The escaping is happening when you set aside the content, not when you display it. Try using `raw` within `content_for`:

```
<% content_for raw :navigation do %>
```